# JSON binding with a nested payload

Tags: go, buffalo

I'm using Go and Buffalo to develop an API.
When receiving a request, it is possible to [automatically map the JSON payload](https://gobuffalo.io/fr/docs/bind#how-does-it-work) to a struct:

```
func MyAction(c buffalo.Context) error {
  u := &User{}
  if err := c.Bind(u); err != nil {
    return err
  }
  u.Name // "Ringo"
  u.Email // "ringo@beatles.com"
}
```

However, it supposes that the payload is of this shape:

```
{
  "name": "Ringo",
  "email": "ringo@beatles.com"
}
```

If for some reason, the incoming payload has a key:

```
{
 "user": {
    "name": "Ringo",
    "email": "ringo@beatles.com"
  } 
}
```

The binding won't work. I couldn't find how to handle this case.
How should I approach this ?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you can wrap your struct with `map[string]User{}`, here is an example:

```
func MyAction(c buffalo.Context) error {
  u := map[string]User{
    "user": User{},
  }
  if err := c.Bind(&u); err != nil {
    return err
  }
  user := u["user"]
  user.Name // "Ringo"
  user.Email // "ringo@beatles.com"
}
```

In my opinion define a struct would be cleaner solution:

```
type UserObject struct {
    User struct {
        Email string
        Name  string
    }
}

func MyAction(c buffalo.Context) error {
   u := UserObject{}
   if err := c.Bind(&u); err != nil {
      return err
   }
   user := u.User
   user.Name // "Ringo"
   user.Email // "ringo@beatles.com"
}
```